# What does Star Pons mean?

Tags: foreign-words

In the poster what does Star Pons mean in English? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @1.21gigawatts! Are you sure this is Italian language? I think it's not.

Comment: Did you see it in Italy? Where? It doesn't sound Italian at all.

Comment: It is from a show that takes place in Italy. It was on the main characters apartment wall. https://twitter.com/antoinepey/status/677967864163385344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Star Pons are a specific breed of Polish Lowland Sheepdogs. If you search online for "Star Pons" you will find several websites devoted to the breed. The logo and poster are in the style of the Star Wars movie poster. Therefore, the logo on the poster is an English-language play on words.

Nothing to do with the Italian Language, by the way, so doubtful it should be on this forum, but hope this helps.